# Differences in psak

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, halacha-theory

Why do we learn Gemara, where each opinion gets equal weight and the strongest opinion wins, and we are thus taught not to be peti, but to only accept a true answer, while today, its enough that one Rabbi said 'this' and we don't bring arguments: if he said it, it's holy of holies. Why not ask questions and find the truth? Just like the Gemara, but today? An example we learn from the first daf of Maseches Horayos where if one who learned knows the halacha and the Sanhedrin was wrong, he should have not listened, but argued until they did a psak. Then he is a zaken mamre if he publicly contradicts the Sanhedrin's ruling, but he must stick to his opinion in private, for if not, then when the Sanhedrin finds they are wrong, he has no kapara from their korban

Comment: You seem to be asking two questions. One about Torah study (why we learn Gemara), and one about ruling legal matters (ruling based on debate). Please clarify this point or split your question into two questions.

Comment: It should be noted that legal (halachic) literature today includes arguments as well, as in the time of the Gemara; question continue to be asked. There is, however, somewhat of a paradigm shift between the methodology of pesak (legal decision making) in the period of the Gemara, and in the present day. That distinction lies in the available authoritative resources. Then, halacha was determined based on the Mishna (and other works of the period). Opinions, of contemporaries were expected to be squared with these. Today, we (generally) dont evaluate the opinions of the Gemara...

Comment: Although sages in that period questioned each other. Our relationship with the Gemara is akin to the relationship between the Ammoraim and the Tannaim. Therefore, the fact that we dont generally challenge the authority of the Gemara doesnt create a disparity with the approach of the Gemara. Regarding post-talmudic authority, poskim (decisors) factor both the stature of the authority espousing a view, and their view of the strength of the arguments. This is parallel to the approach of the Gemara which sometimes proclaims that in disputes between particular sages the law accords with one, ruling

Comment: Bases on the authority of the decisor, while elsewhere, the Gemara determines the bindidng conclusion through logical arguments.

Comment: @mevaqesh ...and im asking why (your second note)

Comment: By the way, most "Gedolim" are contactable. If you feel that they're wrong, you can write them a disproof (it should have good proof, though!!).

Comment: I would love to be enlightened. I want to work out all my questions with a Gadol without him saying "im too small to make a psak on that'

Comment: @user3548935 If I'll come to a Rov and tell him why I think the Mishna Brura is wrong, I'll (rightly) be laughed out of the room. If my Rov says something in Shiur and I'll ask him for a source, and he'll say "It's a clear Shulchan Aruch" and I'll show him how he's wrong, he'll admit his mistake.

Comment: I mean, look at Shaalas U'Teshuvos. There are sources and reasoning going back and forth. Many of these were written in the past 100 years, so even now there are Rabbonim who paskin based on give and take.

Comment: @user3548935 I'm sorry I didnt get that. Are you referring to the question of why the opinion of anyone in any era carries more weight than the apparent force of their evidence>

Comment: Today too if you know a psak to be wrong you ought not rely on it.

Answer (score 2):

When the Amoraim Paskened, the people had to listen to them as well. What you are seeing is the conversation **between the rabbis**.

A side point: Between the arguments we seem to forget that most often, when a greater Amora was quoted, it was taken as a Psak and a proof and not naturally questioned. For example. when [Rav Mori bar Rachel](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%93_%D7%91) got a Psak, he didn't wait until he got convinced. When [Shmuel was quoted](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A2_%D7%91) that was the end of the conversation, not the beginning of the debate. Arguing on a Rebbe was the exception, not the rule.

Nothing changed in this regard. Many Rabbanim argue on their Rabbeim in certain instances.

Comment: People are the amaratzim who knew nothing. You dont learn in kollel for ten years to stay "the people"

Comment: @user3548935 not every guy who went to the Kallah (who by the end of his life may have learned more than people who sit for ten years nowadays) was mentioned in the Gemara

Comment: I think it mattered more if one said things l'inyan. Abaye appeared from a young age for just that reason, as well as countless 'yenukas'

Comment: @user3548935 Rebbe Yehoshua violated his own Yom Kippur. But more importantly, if you are up to par, then surely you will be *discussing* it with your Rav.

Comment: Because otherwise he would have become a zaken mamre. In any case this was not acceptable to Chachmim who  soon replaced Raban Gamliel

Comment: @user3548935 The treatment was not acceptable, not the adherence. He actually went to ask Rebbe Akiva's advice, so it wasn't a matter of Zaken Mamrei. He was not against the Sanhedrin, only Rebbe Gamliel. He was part of deciders.

Comment: Again, the whole Gemara tells us to ask until we receive a satisfactory answer. I wont let one example put me off

Comment: @user3548935 A Psak is a Psak and learning is learning. Go ask and learn, and as you said, if you _know_ that the Posek is making a mistake (i.e. he very obviously forgot the Halacha, or thinks that electricity is fire) you won't listen to him -- and you'll go to someone else. But a Rebbe is a Rebbe. In the Gemara there are more examples of Talmidim, Amoraim, accepting their Rebbe's Psak than the other way around.

Comment: Wonderful, now you understand my question. Today we dont psak, we make this salad to keep everyone happy, as if we dont have the authority. Didnt it say in rosh hashana that the beis din of each generation is like Moshe's?

Comment: @user3548935 The Gemara also says משום שאנו מדמים נעשה מעשה? Rebbe Yochanan says in Shabbos אם ברור לך הדבר כאחותך שהיא אסורה לך אמרהו. Wanting to Pasken is not good enough of a reason to do so. Psak is not about decisively ruling in the direction you lean more, it's about _knowing_. Otherwise we get, even by Tannaim, היה חוכך בזה להחמיר.

Comment: @user3548935 You ask in your question why your Rav has authority, but now ask why he doesn't. I think you weren't being clear.

Comment: @HaLeiVi Rabba and Rava argue at times (beginning of Gittin, second perek of Eiruvin)

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I addressed that. You said it just like I did, at times. Most often it was בעא מיניה and he didn't wait to get convinced.